Disable all Logging Except Error logs from all dependencies
Hi I have multiple services written in Go with multiple OSS dependencies/modules, some of these dependencies might provide a way for change logging levels etc. some might not. I am looking for a way which can apply globally to all these dependencies and disable all logging from these packages/modules except the Error (STDERR) logs.
I tried setting log flag to 0 and log.SetOuput(io.Discard) however it do not work for dependencies and only disable logs in current application module.
I also tried to intercept the stdout logs by Pipe through the stdout stream (os.Pipe), however there also it only captures the current module's stdout it seems and the dependencies modules logs flows without getting intercepted, it was a little confusing, do every module in Go has it's own stdout and stderr streams ?
Is there a global way top solve this problem ?

«do every module in Go has it's own stdout and stderr streams?»–no. The effect has a simpler explanation: the os.Std* are variables, and they are not magic, which means that changes to them only affect code which reads them after they have been modified. Since the dependency packages are initialized before the main one, they read the values of os.Std* variables before the change done by you in the main package.

«Is there a global way top solve this problem?»–Yes, but I would advise against it because such a solution would be an awful anti-pattern which could be sort-of okay for functional testing but not otherwise. I think your best bet is to 1) fork the dependencies which do not have proper logging tweaks; 2) implement these tweaks locally; 3) upstream them; 4) while they're gettiing upstreamed, live with forked versions, rebasing your changes as you update these deps when necessary. See this.

«do every module in Go has it's own stdout and stderr streams?»–note that the standard I/O streams is the concept of a process (running with the help of an OS kernel), so different modules/packages cannot have "their own" standard I/O streams. See this.
